# Keep iPhone from sleeping

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can I keep the iPhone from sleeping?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

To stop your app from timing out and going to sleep you can use:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```

This will, obviously, disable the idle timer and stop your iphone from automatically going into sleep mode.

Edit: As middaparka stated you should re-enable the idle timer when you no longer need to keep the phone awake (generally after that view has been removed) using:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = NO;
```

Cheers

Comment: Or viewWillDisappear.

Comment: Brilliant, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 27):

You can disable the automatic locking via...

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
```

However, you should really only do this within as few sections of your app as possible, and then re-enable it via...

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:NO];
```

...in the relevant view controller's `viewWillDisappear:`
 or `dealloc`.