# Simulate sleep mode on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, brightness, sleep-mode

I have an App that is all day working in the same place and need a way to simulate a sleep mode as best as possible during a range of time.

I thought a simple solution, adding a black view... but sure there are better options. Can I control the brightness of the screen of the device? Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: you can control the brightness: [UIScreen mainScreen].brightness = 0.5;

Comment: thanks Tony, its any way to make sure that the iPad not enter in sleep mode?

Comment: to disable sleep mode use this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5236619/1702413 you can read about that also here (Turning Off Screen Locking) https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW63

Comment: Welcome, Pay it forward! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally an app that's running but has no user interaction for some period of time causes iOS to go into its own sleep mode. So your app sets that condition to keep the UI active all the time?

If so, sure, add a view to the window and animate it from transparent to full black. Put a gesture recognizer on it so if the user taps it, you animate back into  translucent mode, then remove the view.

Comment: It is likely his apps runs in kiosk mode, and works all the time.

Comment: Thanks David and Leo. Yes, my app is running 24 hours but i need minimice the screen wastage.

Comment: I think that i mix this solution with the TonyMkenu [UIScreen mainScreen].brightness = 0.5;