# Oculus Go: How to keep awake while still in app

Tags: oculusgo

I'm working on an Oculus Go app, using Unity, where the user is literally expected to sleep while using the app and with the headset still on their head.  I seem to be running into the problem where the Oculus Go goes into power-save mode because of inactivity.  Presumably, the user isn't moving enough when they are in a deep sleep.

Although I've included instructions for the user on how to disable sleep as a device-wide setting, this is far from ideal. iOS has idleTimerDisabled ([Keep iPhone from sleeping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236598/keep-iphone-from-sleeping)) which is a simple one-line stay-awake type of command. I'm looking for the Oculus Go equivalent of iOS's idleTimerDisabled

Does anyone have any hints on how to keep the Oculus Go from turning off?

Just to be clear, this stay-awake behavior should only happen while the user is wearing the headset and using the this app, and only this app.  If the user takes off the headset, normal turn-off behavior should be immediately restored.

Thanks in advance,
JJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of May 2019, it is not possible to keep the Oculus Go awake.  Oculus wrote to me

> Unfortunately, this doesn't look to be functionality (disabling sleep when there is no movement) that is available at this time.

Comment: After some discussion with Oculus, I've submitted a bug report/feature request. So, let's hope this gets addressed in a future release.

Comment: After Oculus Connect 6, their engineers confirmed that no-sleep just is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Include

```
Screen.sleepTimeout = SleepTimeout.NeverSleep;
```

in your MonoBehaviour script if you just want keep the device awake while app is running and helmet is worn.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-sleepTimeout.html

Comment: This might be true, but I haven't been able to test this with the latest Go OS.  They seem to have changed the mechanism behind going to sleep.

Comment: @JJRohrer True. All of our previous projects, which weren't published in store, now have this issue unless this line is included.

Comment: I've tested on latest Go OS and it seems to be getting ignored. I'm thinking the OS is making its own decision based on user movement.